# How do I check if the second letter is equal to a with regex?

Tags: regex, grep

I need to match a string which second letter is "a", my current regex is:
   `^([^a-zA-Z]*[a-zA-Z][^a-zA-Z]*)a+`
but this matches less than I need, I dont even know what It doesnt match but do you know where is the problem, or if there is a better way of doing this?
For example I need to match these:

```
"  kamcnn"
",.,ya..--/**+-00"
"0        0   q    a"
```

I match every string that I can imagine but Im still getting lower results than I should get.
EDIT: By "letter" I mean a character from [a-zA-Z] class.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "second letter is a"... From the strings you've provided it seems like you're just looking for 'a' to exist somewhere in the string.

Comment: Looks okay to me, perhaps you need to match uppercase as well?  If so, use `^([^a-zA-Z]*[a-zA-Z][^a-zA-Z]*)[aA]`

Comment: Hmm, no, tested it, same results. I found 23389 lines, but I should have found 26639.

Comment: In the example you gave, what does your regex miss?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
^[^a-zA-Z]*[a-zA-Z][^a-zA-Z]*a.*
```

This matches the entire string if the second ASCII letter is `a`:

```
^           # Start of string
[^a-zA-Z]*  # Match any number of non-letters
[a-zA-Z]    # Match one ASCII letter
[^a-zA-Z]*  # Match any number of non-letters
a           # Match an a
.*          # Match whatever follows
```

Comment: Hmm, no, tested it, same results. I found 23389 lines, but I should have found 26639.

Comment: Show one of the lines that didn't match but should have.